# Fetch Post of formData with images works in iOS but on android returns 400 BAD REQUEST

Tags: react-native, multipartform-data, fetch-api, form-data

`I am using fetch on react native to send a post request with a form data object on the body.

This code works on iOS but on android it returns a 400 BAD REQUEST and I get  ERROR  [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF].

```
const buildFormData = () => {
const data = new FormData();
for (let i = 0; i < photoForm.photosToUpload.length; i++) {
console.log(photoForm.photosToUpload[i].uri)
data.append('photosToUpload', {
uri: photoForm.photosToUpload[i].uri,
name: photoForm.photosToUpload[i].fileName,
type: 'image/jpeg'
            });

data.append("userForm", JSON.stringify(userForm));
console.log(data)
return data;
    }
```

This is how I am building my form data.

```
export const createUser = (formData) => async (dispatch) => {
try {
const headers = {
         'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
     };
const response = await fetch('https://c66d-2a02-a03f-a5a1-e400-1573-78c6-e019-e601.eu.ngrok.io' + '/create_user', {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
Accept: 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
body: formData,
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseJson => {
console.log(responseJson);
  })
  .catch(error => {
console.error(error);
  });
Handle successful response
catch (error) {
 Handle error
  }
```

This is how I am sending the form data to my django server. I know the problem is in the form data because if I dont send files the request goes through.

I have read almost every github issue on this matter, switched to axios, tried multiple solutions and no luck. Does anyone know what the problem can be?

I tried to make a post request using fetch and it works on iOS but not on android.
I was expecting to work on both OS.`